# Writing the output of a command to a file in a bash script

Tags: shell-script, files, error-handling, write

I am trying to write a simple bash script that executes the command `tcprobe -i $1` where `$1` is an mp4 file.  Then, I want to write the output of this command, which should be a long string of information about the video file, to a file called frameInfo.

My code currently is:

```
#/bin/bash
echo (tcprobe -i $1) > frameInfo
```

However, this writes the output of `tcprobe` to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need your echo nor parenthesis here. Checking `$1` was defined could be relevant as well:

```
#!/bin/sh

if test "$#" -eq 0; then
    echo missing argument
    exit 1
fi >&2

if test "$DEBUG"; then
    set -x
    tcprobe -i "$1"
    echo returned $?
    set +x
else
    tcprobe -i "$1" >frameInfo 2>&1
fi

exit 0
```

use `DEBUG=toto ./your/script yourFileArgument`, to enable debugs.

Comment: If `echo` fails, that fails to exit the script. It's better to use proper `if`/`then` constructs here than to chain `&&`d commands.

Comment: This ended up not writing anything to the file.  I added an echo $1 as an additional check, and it printed the proper value.

Comment: You can try running that script commenting out the last redirection (starting at `>frameInfo`, insert a `#`) to confirm the command is properly running. Isn't there an error message at least?

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit did not fix my problem.